# How to join 2 tables that share 1 colum with same ID and add WHERE clause to it

Tags: php, mysql, join, where-clause

Well, the title says it all.

I have tried several things none of them worked till now I have this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ".$CFG['table']['menuaddons']." m
JOIN ".$CFG['table']['addons']." t1 ON m.addonparentid = t1.id
JOIN ".$CFG['table']['addons']." t2 ON m.addonparentid = t2.id
";
```

This returns all the items. Now I only want to show the items where the `m.addonparentid` is a variable `$parentid`.

When I do:

```
SELECT *
FROM ".$CFG['table']['menuaddons']." m
JOIN ".$CFG['table']['addons']." t1 ON m.addonparentid = t1.id
JOIN ".$CFG['table']['addons']." t2 ON m.addonparentid = t2.id
WHERE m.addonparentid = '".$menuaddonsid."'
";
```

I get an empty array back? And when that works I want to sort it `DESC` on a column name called `addonsort` in `.$CFG['table']['addons'].`.

I have checked all info about join but could not find how to do this.

Comment: can you give the schema of the three tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little tricky to work this out without knowing a) your intention and b) the schema of the tables involved. Why do you need the add-ons table in the query twice?

Maybe this will work?

```
$query = "SELECT *
FROM " . $CFG['table']['menuaddons'] . " m
INNER JOIN " . $CFG['table']['addons'] . " t1 ON m.addonparentid = t1.id
WHERE m.addonparentid = " . $parentid . "
ORDER BY t1.addonsort DESC";
```

If not, please post more information.
Once you have it working, please consider converting this to using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) - the current query is vulnerable to SQL injection, depending on where the variables come from.